# AD Searches and Properties and dictonary usage

Tags: c#, dictionary, active-directory

In order to determine if computer accounts are orphaned, I would like to query all domain controllers of all trusted domains to retrieve the lastLogon and lastLogonTimeStamp for all computers.  I have a program that works (at least in my test environment), but I have a few questions, that I hope you might be able to answer.

1. Are the methods I’m using to find the domains and domain controllers and then retrieve the AD information, using the least amount of resources (network / domain controller CPU and RAM) as possible? How could they be improved?
2. Is it possible to have more than 1 value in a dictionary key / value  pair? 
   Having a dictionary for LastLogIn and a different one for LastLogInTimestamp seems a waste.
3. Referring to the dictionary and the AD properties: How can I check for non-existent values as opposed to using Try / Catch?

   try
   {  // Is this DC more current than the last?
      if (dict_LastLogIn[pc] < (long)result.Properties["lastlogon"][0])
      {
        dict_LastLogIn[pc] = (long)result.Properties["lastlogon"][0];
      }
   }
   catch
   {   // The item doesn't exist yet..
      try
      {
        dict_LastLogIn[pc] = (long)result.Properties["lastlogon"][0];
      }
      catch
      { // .. or
        // There is no last LastLogin...
        dict_LastLogIn[pc] = 0;
      }
   }

Here the entire code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.DirectoryServices;
using System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory;


namespace dictionary
{
    class Program
    {
        internal static Dictionary<string, long> dict_LastLogIn =
            new Dictionary<string, long>();
        internal static Dictionary<string, long> dict_LastLogInTimeStamp =
            new Dictionary<string, long>();
        internal static Dictionary<string, DateTime> output =
            new Dictionary<string, DateTime>();

        internal static bool AreAllDCsResponding = true;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.BufferWidth = 150;
            Console.BufferHeight = 9999;
            Console.WindowWidth = 150;

            Dictionary<String, int> dict_domainList = new Dictionary<String, int>();
            Dictionary<String, int> dict_dcList = new Dictionary<String, int>();

            //Get the current domain's trusts.
            Domain currentDomain = Domain.GetCurrentDomain();
            Console.WriteLine("Retrieved the current Domain as {0}", currentDomain.ToString());
            var domainTrusts = currentDomain.GetAllTrustRelationships();
            Console.WriteLine("  {0} trusts were found.", domainTrusts.Count);
            //Add the current domain to the dictonary.  It won't be in domainTrusts!
            dict_domainList.Add(currentDomain.ToString(), 0);
            // Then add the other domains to the dictonary...
            foreach (TrustRelationshipInformation trust in domainTrusts)
            {
                dict_domainList.Add(trust.TargetName.Substring(0, trust.TargetName.IndexOf(".")).ToUpper(), 0);
                Console.WriteLine("    Adding {0} to the list of trusts.", trust.TargetName.Substring(0, trust.TargetName.IndexOf(".")).ToUpper());
            }
            // Now get all DCs per domain
            foreach (var pair in dict_domainList)
            {
                DirectoryContext dc = new DirectoryContext(DirectoryContextType.Domain, pair.Key);
                Domain _Domain = Domain.GetDomain(dc);
                foreach (DomainController Server in _Domain.DomainControllers)
                {
                    dict_dcList.Add(Server.Name, 0);
                    Console.WriteLine("      Adding {0} to the list of DCs.", Server.Name.ToUpper());

                }
                // Now search through every DC
                foreach (var _pair in dict_dcList)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("        Querying {0} for Computer objects.", _pair.Key.ToUpper());
                    Search(pair.Key);
                    Console.WriteLine("\n");
                    Console.WriteLine("The following Computer objects were found:");
                }

                if (AreAllDCsResponding == true)
                {
                    ConvertTimeStamp(dict_LastLogIn);
                }
                else
                {
                    ConvertTimeStamp(dict_LastLogInTimeStamp);
                }
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }

        internal static void Search(string domainName)
        {
            DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + domainName);
            DirectorySearcher mySearcher = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
            mySearcher.Filter = ("(&(ObjectCategory=computer))");//(lastlogon=*)(lastlogonTimeStamp=*))");
            mySearcher.SizeLimit = int.MaxValue;
            mySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("DistinguishedName");
            mySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("lastlogon");
            mySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("lastlogonTimeStamp");
            try
            {
                foreach (System.DirectoryServices.SearchResult result in mySearcher.FindAll())
                {
                    string pc = result.Properties["DistinguishedName"][0].ToString();
                    try
                    {   // Is this DC more current than the last?
                        if (dict_LastLogIn[pc] < (long)result.Properties["lastlogon"][0])
                        {
                            dict_LastLogIn[pc] = (long)result.Properties["lastlogon"][0];
                        }
                    }
                    catch
                    {   // The item doesn't exist yet..
                        try
                        {
                            dict_LastLogIn[pc] = (long)result.Properties["lastlogon"][0];
                        }
                        catch
                        {   // .. or
                            // There is no last LastLogin...
                            dict_LastLogIn[pc] = 0;
                        }
                    }

                    try
                    {
                        // Not yet replicated?...
                        if (dict_LastLogInTimeStamp[pc] < (long)result.Properties["lastlogonTimeStamp"][0])
                        {
                            dict_LastLogInTimeStamp[pc] = (long)result.Properties["lastlogonTimeStamp"][0];
                        }
                    }
                    catch
                    {   // The item doesn't exist yet..
                        try
                        {
                            dict_LastLogInTimeStamp[pc] = (long)result.Properties["lastlogonTimeStamp"][0];
                        }
                        catch
                        {   // .. or
                            // There is no last LastLoginTimeStamp...
                            dict_LastLogInTimeStamp[pc] = 0;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException)
            {
                //If even one DC doesn't answer, don't use LastLogon!  
                //Use the less accurate, but replicated(!) LastLogonTimeStamp. 
                AreAllDCsResponding = false;
            }
        }

        internal static void ConvertTimeStamp(Dictionary<string, long> _dict)
        {
            foreach (var pair in _dict)
            {
                output.Add(pair.Key, DateTime.FromFileTime(pair.Value));
                Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", pair.Key, DateTime.FromFileTime(pair.Value));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 0):

At a high level, I'm not sure what your end-game is with this, but, are you sure you really want to query every single DC for lastLogon? This could be really expensive. Also, why are you walking trust chains? Are you sure you don't just want all the domains in a given Forest (`Forest.Domains`)?

In answer to your questions:

1. This looks OK perf-wise, however you should do a couple things:

   - Tweak your filter to `(&(objectCategory=computer)(objectClass=computer))`
   - Add `mySearcher.PageSize = 1000`
   - Remove `mySearcher.SizeLimit = int.MaxValue`
2. You could use a `Tuple` - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple(VS.90).aspx. Or just define a custom class as your value and then declare Dictionary as your dictionary:

   public class LogonTimeStamps
   {

   public long LastLogon { get; set; }

   public long LastLogonTimeStamp { get; set; }

   }
3. For the Dictionary, use `myDictionary.ContainsKey(yourKey)`. For AD, you should be able to use `result.Properties.Contains("yourAttribute")`.

Comment: Brian, thanks for your input.  – Endgame? Of course there is always more… I need the information for all domains in our multiple forests, hence the Trusts. For the one, it will update a database with the most current possible “Last AD Connection Time”.  Computers not connected to the network for say 1 year, will be disabled.  As to 1, your filter is of course better.  Why reduce the PageSize?  Is there a benefit?   I’ll be receiving about 10000 results per query, so MaxSize can’t stay at default of 1000.

Comment: 2. Using the dictionary, I can access the pair based on the distinguished name directly, without looping.  Can Tuples or custom classes do that to? How? Sorry, but I’m not a programmer, just an admin looking to expand my tool set…  3. I’ll have to look into that.  -  I also think that just prior to foreaching each DC, I will ping them, which will save up to two minutes per non-reachable DC.

Comment: AD's Max Default Page Size is 1000 unless someone tinkered with it. The `DirectorySearcher` will automatically page the records as long as you set this. The `SizeLimit` parameter isn't necessary. As far as the Dictionary, you'll store `Dictionary<string, LogonTimeStamp>`, so you'll still access it via the DN. Finally for perf, you may also want to look at multithreading so you query each DC in an individual thread. You can do this fairly easily with the `ThreadPool` class.

Comment: I only get 1000 results if I don't set MaxSize.  Maybe something was modified.    Multithreading sounds excellent, but what hapens if two or more threads try changing the same key/value pair at the same time in the dictionary?  Assuming I wanted to thread `Search(pair.Key);` how could that be implemented?

Comment: The multithreading thing is really a totally seperate question IMO. At a high level, you use the lock() keyword to handle the concurrency. I'm not sure why SizeLimit is playing in here - the docs say it's ignored for >1000. PageSize is the important one here.